# How to get PaymentIntent next_action.type = redirect_to_url instead of use_stripe_sdk for Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on the implementing Subscription*(which is SCA ready) using Stripe.
I try to handle https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-action-required.
After the subscription is created on Stripe side, I have got the answer like in documentation above:

```
{
  "id": "sub_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "object": "subscription",
  "status": "incomplete",
  ...
  "latest_invoice": {
    ...
    "payment_intent": {
      "status": "requires_action",
      ...
      "next_action": {
        "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

According to the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action-type
`next_action.type` can have two values `redirect_to_url` and `use_stripe_sdk`

So my question is how to get `next_action.type = redirect_to_url`(instead of `use_stripe_sdk`) and how to force stripe to fill `next_action.redirect_to_url`(Because I want to handle it on my own in my UI)?

*There is already a similar question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490033/how-to-handle-use-stripe-sdk-through-php
but my case is to create **Subscription** where I don't have control over PaymentIntent

Comment: Call [confirm](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm) on the PaymentIntent from the invoice(`latest_invoice.payment_intent.id`) and pass [`return_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-return_url). That will give you an updated PaymentIntent with the `redirect_to_url` action.

Comment: @karllekko I try to redirect to next_action.redirect_to_url.url
via set header `Location url` but stripe return `404` HTTP status for OPTION request(Preflight CORS request). Is it intentional?

Comment: @karllekko that used to work but it seems to no longer work :/

Comment: @snieguu What karllekko posted used to work (also in my code) but all of the sudden it doesn't work anymore. I have the same issue here. I contacted Stripe support to see why

Comment: @JorisMans can you clarify what you mean by 'not working'? I've just tried it and it seems to work : https://repl.it/repls/SurprisedLightsalmonRecords (confirming the PaymentIntent with a `return_url` changes the next action type).

Comment: @snieguu I think that's intentional yes, you should do the redirect by setting `window.location.href` in JS instead

Comment: @karllekko For me `paymentIntent.confirm(paymentIntentUpdateParams)` stop working. Now I have error `Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication.; code: authentication_required; request-id: req_uD911EMa4dkG2P` I use card `4000000000003220` from https://stripe.com/docs/testing#three-ds-cards.

Comment: @JorisMans It seems that everything came back to work for me.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be a bug at Stripe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my understanding, the [`next_action.type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action-type) will be equal to `redirect_to_url` only if you choose to manually handle 3D Secure authentication https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#manual-3ds-auth

As per documentation:

> To handle 3D Secure authentication manually, you can redirect the customer. This approach is used when you manually confirm the PaymentIntent and provide a [`return_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-return_url) destination to indicate where the customer should be sent once authentication is complete. Manual PaymentIntent confirmation can be performed [on the server](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#manual-confirmation-flow) or on the client [with Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-confirm-payment-intent).

Example using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-confirm-payment-intent):

```
stripe.confirmPaymentIntent(
  '{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}',
  {
    payment_method: '{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}',
    return_url: 'https://example.com/return_url'
  }
).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
});
```

Example using [Stripe Python](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python):

```
intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.confirm(
  '{PAYMENT_INTENT_ID}',
  payment_method='{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}',
  return_url='https://example.com/return_url'
)
```

EDIT: as per [@karllekko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9769731/karllekko) comment the `{PAYMENT_INTENT_ID}` will in your case be `latest_invoice.payment_intent.id`.

Comment: The correct answer is the first comment from @karllekko

Comment: @snieguu My answer is a follow-up with all the links, details and snippets. There is nothing wrong in posting an answer after someone included it in a comment and didn't post the answer himself :)

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure-iframe - it gives more details about the "return_url" flow - and describes also posibilities to customize it inside "iframe" etc

Probably this document is fairly recent - so at the time of this question (July) it was not existing yet